# Removing object from another object - unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript

I can't solve this unexpected behavior with this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps9ew500/1/) code.
Basically I am trying to remove words such as `cars,ford,carsforsale`. If you check console data output is without `ford` and `carsforsale` but `cars` is still in object. I do not know why. Can someone show me correct way to remove this nested objects? Thanks

code:

```
var data = [{"key":"ford","doc_count":8967},{"key":"cars","doc_count":4684},{"key":"carsforsale","doc_count":2487},{"key":"forddaytona","doc_count":1220},{"key":"daytona500","doc_count":1176},{"key":"forsale","doc_count":1171}]

        for (var i in data) {
            if ((data[i]['key'] == 'ford') || (data[i]['key'] == 'cars') || (data[i]['key'] == 'carsforsale')) {
                console.log(data[i]['key']);
                delete(data[i]);
                data.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Comment: Don't use `for .. in` to iterate arrays. Use its `Array#forEach`, `Array#map`, or a `for .. of`

Comment: Just remove the `data.splice(...)` statement. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're removing elements from the object you are iterating while you are iterating it. This means things will shift down by 1 every time you remove, but you will continue to move forward in your list and thus miss some elements.

Just traverse the list in reverse or do `i--` when you delete an element.

For example:

```
-> i = 0, it points at ford
-> you delete ford
-> everything moves down by 1
-> i = 0, now points at cars
-> you increase i by 1
-> i =1, it points at carsforsale
```

you are never going to point at `cars`

Comment: Thank you for great explanation! now I can easily correct my wrong code implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You've several problems in the code:

1. don't use `for .. in` to iterate over arrays
2. don't use `delete` to remove elements from arrays - it does remove the data, but leaves the key in place
3. be *very* careful when using `splice` to modify an array while it's being iterated

In this case, your problem is that each time you call `.splice` your indices change - the remaining elements following the deleted index will be shuffled down by one, yet you're still iterating over the original range.  The immediately following element will be ignored because you already handled that index.

If would be far simpler to use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create a new array which omits the unwanted elements:

```
let newArray = oldArray.filter(
  e => e.key !== 'ford' && e.key !== 'cars' && e.key !== 'carsforsale'
);
```

or with destructuring:

```
let newArray = oldArray.filter(
  ({ key }) => key !== 'ford' && key !== 'cars' && key !== 'carsforsale'
);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but your suggestion is doing opposite thing => it creates new array only with those elements. I want new object without those unwanted elements.

Comment: @bzadm oops - sorry about that - fixed now!